# How to disable accessing the custom post types from frontend via a link?

Tags: admin, links, front-end

I am registering a custom post type like:

```
/* POST TYPE: SECRET CARDS */
function register_post_type_secret_cards()
    {
        $args = array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Secret Cards',
                'singular_name' => 'Secret Card',
                'add_new' => 'Add New Item',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Item',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
                'new_item' => 'Add New Item',
                'view_item' => 'View Items',
                'search_items' => 'Search Items',
                'not_found' => 'No Item Found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Items Found in Trash'
            ),
            'query_var' => 'secret_cards',
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'secret-cards/',
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 4,
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
            )
        );

        register_post_type('secret_cards', $args);

    }
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_type_secret_cards' );
```

And these cards are accessible from frontend like:

```
http://myweb.com/secret-cards/john-wayne
```

But I want to not allow people to access these iks from frontend. It should be accessible only in admin.

How to do that?

Answer (score 6):

I think setting `'publicly_queryable' => false` should solve your problem!

Comment: Why is this not green?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, just don't publish the post. On the top right in the post edit section you have several options to do this.

Comment: No, that's not an option in my situation. It have to be done programmatically. If published, draft etc. that should has no effect.